# c ++ pointer puzzle

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *pn;
    char *pc;
    char c = 0x65;
    pn = (int *)&c;
    int n = *pn;
    *pn = 0x12345678;
    cout << "*pn: " << hex << *pn << dec << endl;
    cout << "n: " << hex << n << dec << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result of this program execution is:

```
*pn: 12345678
n: 123456
```

env: I use Windows 10 and Clion to write program.
More puzzled:
1.this sentence `int n = * pn;` means that the value of `n` is `* pn`, and the value of `* pn` is `0x65`, that is, the value of `n` is `0x65`. It should be unchanged after that, why do `* pn = 0x12345678;` After that, the value of `n` becomes `0x123456`?
2.when run `int n = *pn;`, the `*pn` value become dec 25957, which hex 0x6565, how does this happend? you can see this in picture 3!
I hope that the experts can answer their doubts, thank you here!
the debug picture is：
1
[image: the first debug img]
2
[image: the second debug img]
3
[image: the third debug img]
4
[image: the fourth debug img]

Comment: This is undefined behavior, that's all there is to it.

Comment: When you do "*pn = 0x12345678" you are overwriting parts of the stack (corrupting memory). The stack memory where n is stored is being overwritten. This is undefined behavior and could do anything from crash your program to not cause any harm.

Comment: I think n has a separate memory address. Its value should not be overwritten, but it is overwritten. Why is this happening?

Comment: Because when you change `*pn`, you are changing parts of `n`. As Blaze said, this is UB. You get what you get.

Comment: "the value of `*pn` is `0x65`" - nope, `int n = *pn;` is just bad, because `pn` doesn't point at an `int` object at all.

Comment: many thanks, but when run int n = *pn;, the *pn value become dec 25957, which hex 0x6565, how does this happend? you can see it in debug img 3

Answer (score 4):

`&c` is a pointer to a single byte of memory, by casting it to `int*` you are changing it to a pointer to (usually) 4 bytes of memory however there is still only a single byte of memory in the `c` variable. Any change performed through the `pn` pointer will attempt to write 4 bytes of memory to `c`, this is undefined behaviour.

What is likely happening is that all of your variables are laid out next to each other on the stack so when you write out of the bounds of `c` the writes overwrite one or more of the adjacent variables. You can't rely on this being the exact behaviour though as it is undefined.

Comment: thansks, your answer question 1, hope you answer the question 2.

Comment: many thanks, but when run int n = *pn;, the *pn value become dec 25957, which hex 0x6565, how does this happend? you can see it in debug img 3

Comment: Its undefined behvaiour, anything can happen, reasoning about whats happening past "I've done something bad, I should expect bad things to happen" is futile

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> char c = 0x65;
> pn = (int *)&c;
> int n = *pn;
> ```

You reinterpret `char*` as `int*`. When you attempt to access a non-existing `int` through the reinterpreted (and potentially misaligned) pointer, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

> but it is overwritten. Why is this happening?

It happens because behaviour of the program is undefined.

> the *pn value become dec 25957, which hex 0x6565, how does this happend?

It happens because behaviour of the program is undefined.

Comment: thansks, your answer question 1, hope you answer the question 2.

Comment: many thanks, but when run int n = *pn;, the *pn value become dec 25957, which hex 0x6565, how does this happend? you can see it in debug img 3

Comment: @user2712836 added answer to second question.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of argument, let's say that `c` occupies one byte in memory.  Also, let's say that an `int` occupies 4 bytes in memory.

The expression `int * pn = (int *) &c;` makes a pointer **to a 4 byte memory** point to a **one byte** memory.  No problems so far (pointers can point to anywhere).

The statement: `*pn = 0x12345678;` assigns a 4 byte value to a one byte memory location (remember that `c` is only one byte in memory).

```
   +---+  
c: |   |  
   +---+  

     +---+---+---+---+  
pn-> |   |   |   |   |  
     +---+---+---+---+
```

The `int` requires more room in memory than you have allocated.

Changing a pointer's type does not allocate more memory.

**Edit 1: Possible overwrite**
One possible scenario is overwriting memory.

```
      100   101   102   103  
     +-----+-----+-----+-----+  
c:   | 65  |     |     |     |  
pn-> |     |     |     |     |  
     +-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

After `*pn = 0x12345678;`:

```
      100   101   102   103  
     +-----+-----+-----+-----+  
c:   | 12  | 34  | 56  | 78  |  
pn-> |     |     |     |     |  
     +-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

If overwriting doesn't cause any exceptions, you have no idea what variables are located at addresses 101, 102 or 103.  So you may be overwriting other variables.
(The above diagram assumes Big Endian layout).

There are other scenarios (such as the variable `c` is allocated at the end of memory), thus you will be writing past the end of memory.

The behavior is undefined.

**Edit 2: Reading - undefined behavior**
In general, memory contains *random* values (values from other programs, values that are not initialized).

Given memory with random values (after initializing `c` variable):

```
      100   101   102   103  
     +-----+-----+-----+-----+  
c:   | 65  | ?F0 | ?0D | ?CD |  
pn-> |     |     |     |     |  
     +-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Dereferencing the `pn` pointer (as a 4-byte) quantity results in 0x65F00DCD (Big Endian).  Dereferencing in Little Endian Platforms:  0xCD0DF065.  The `'?'` represents an uninitialized value.

This is only one possible scenario.  If `c` is located at the last addressable memory location, your program may generate a SEGFAULT for access memory outside the boundary.

**Reading multiple times**
Many possible scenarios.  Another scenario is that the same location is read multiple times.  So in the above diagrams, dereferencing `pn` (a.k.a. `*pn`) could result in the value `0x65656565`.

Comment: many thanks, but when run `int n = *pn;`, the `*pn` value become dec 25957, which hex 0x6565, how does this happend?  you can see it in debug img 3